# React component not rendering props coming from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 class CyInfo extends Component {

    foo(){
        console.log(this.props.id);
        return getAttributes(this.props.id)
    }

    render() {
        return ( <Info data = {this.foo()}> </Info>)
    }
}
```

this parent receive "props.id" and pass data value to children which is returned by getAttributes().

```
export default class Info extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    /*componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps);
    */

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
            <div id="info">{this.props.data}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

On child i can see props value on the console and in componentWillReceiveProps also.But array not rendering. 
I try the use react-devtool. In react-devtool props seems passes the children but not rendering.    Interestingly in react-devtool when i change the some of array's element array is rendering.

What did i do wrong.

EDIT:
[React-Devtool Screenshot][1]

I edited the react-devtool screenshot. Props are seems but component only renders initial value. In screenshot console error is favicon just ignore this

EDIT2:[Console prints props array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiU5Y.png)

EDIT 3:
[JSON.stringify(this.props.data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjWNq.png)

Comment: Do u see any errors/warnings on console ? what is the data passed ? its an array.. what kind of array.. whatt are you trying to display ?

Comment: Try `{JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}`. The reason why it might not be showing is because it's not text, but a JavaScript object.

Comment: i edited the question with react-devtool and console screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props are coming from function(getattributes) which is call a method asynchronous and when this props passed the child there are not rendering. 
I call async method directly in parent child and set state with callback in componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    self = this;
    AsyncFunc(nextProps.id ,(error, result) => {
        self.setState({data:result})
    });
}
```

and render with

```
    return (<div id="info">
        {Array.isArray(this.state.data) && this.state.data.map((data) => {
            return <div key={data._id}>{data.class}{data.predicate}{data.yuklem}</div>
        })}</div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

As `foo` is a function, you have to pass to child component as:

```
return ( <Info data = {() => this.foo()}> </Info>)
```

Also, **data** is an **array**, you have to render using [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example), as follows:

```
export default class Info extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    /*componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps);
    */

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
           <div id="info">{this.props.data.map(( element, index ) => {
            console.log(element);
            <span key={index}> {element}</span>})}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I passed props this way but not changes

Comment: What `console.log(this.props.data);` printing?

Comment: i edited the screenshot react-devtool. Console printing also same array

Comment: thanks for reply , i guess element will {element} in span. But still prints init value. is it important where i get props in parent component. I have an cytoscape object in CyInfo's parent and it's cy.on()(async) triggered redux dispatch and CyInfo get this props with mapStateToProps.

Comment: for all that in devtool and console props array passed the child, i don't understand why it's not render

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that `this.data.props` returns an array, and in order to render elements within an array, you need to map over the array elements and also check that the `data is an array or not` before rendering as initially the value may not be available or not an array

```
export default class Info extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    /*componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps);
    */

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
            <div id="info">
               {this.props.data && Array.isArray(this.props.data) && this.props.data.map((data, index) => {
                      return <div key={index}>{data}</div>
               })}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Console warning : Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. I try print "<li key={index}>{data}</li>" in <div></div>. Still warning continues, in render when i say console.log(index,data) , console prints "0,init value"

Comment: warning can be eliminated by using a key over the element returned from map. whatever is the outermost element in map, you need to add key onthat

Comment: i added key for <div>. Now warning eleminated but still don't render array, and console.log(index,data) prints "0,init value" still also.

Comment: what is init value

Comment: "gokhan" is init value

Comment: It should print values like 0, gokhan 1, http:// and so on.. considering your array has 22 elements. can you console.log(this.props.data.length) in render and see you get only 22 printed an nothing else

Comment: In render i can access the props array(chrome console says just evulated now). But when i try your suggestion 
 props array's length is always 1. Is props came after render, but it will rerender when props changed. Am i wrong

Comment: Yes it should rerender with the updated props once they come. You don't get length to be 22, also if you log this.props.data do you see array getting printed in console. Can you console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.data)) and attach the result in the question

Comment: Yes i can see array if i log this.props.data but length is 1 always

Comment: Can you add the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.data))`

Comment: I added the result in question. Its print init value also, but when i log (this.props.data) it's give all array.

Comment: Any other error in console, also log in CyInfo component values of getAttributes

Comment: no error in console. When i try log in CyInfo component getAttributes returned expected array.

Comment: What about its length

Comment: lenght is 0 , array is returned with data but length is 0. I don't understand

Comment: It would have logged it multiple time, initially 0, then something else ,see

Comment: length is 1 with init value , i deleted while trying some other thing. So length is 0 i said, but it's 1 with init statement.

Comment: it will logged it multiple yes, initially 0 but later i initialized the "gokhan" , and it will stay just.Then triggered by click and func getAttributes executed and array filled another strings. Array come to child with this filled values buth lenght is not change , still init length. When i logged i see datas but length is always  1